# When does this matrix have no solultions, infinite solutions and 1 solution? And what are the solutions?

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

So im supposed to decide for what h and k this matrix has no solultions, infinite solutions and a unique solution

$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1&h&1\\
  3&3&k\\
 \end{array}
\right]$$

By gaussian elimination i get

$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1&h&1\\
  0&3-3h&k-3\\
  \end{array}
\right] $$

So i should get no solutions when  $$3-3h = 0 \: ,k-3 \neq 0, \: and  \: 3-3h\neq k-3  $$

And infinitely many solutions when $$3-3h = 0\text{ and }k-3= 0$$
And a unique solution would take the form

$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1&0&\frac{3-kh}{3-3h}\\
  0&1&\frac{k-3}{3-3h}\\
  \end{array}
\right] $$

when $$\: 3-3h\neq 0$$

Are there any cases i have failed to take into consideration?

Comment: You get unique solution when $3-3h \ne 0$. This is sufficient.

Comment: Why did you multiply denominator and numerator with $h$ in the second line ? This was unnecessary. And there also is a typo : it must be $kh-3h$

Comment: @Peter well i did it so i could subtract 3-3h from h to get 0. I just forgot to convert it back after. And yes its a typo

Comment: You get no solution iff $3-3h=0$ and $k-3\neq0$.  That $3-3h\neq k-2$ thing isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get a unique solution when the rows of the coefficient matrix are linearly independent, for then the coefficient matrix is invertible. this happens if $h \neq 1.$ If $h=1,$ the rows of the coefficient matrix are dependent, and you will get no or infinitely many solutions depending on the value of $k.$ If $k=3,$ the rows of the augmented matrix are dependent, and you get infinitely many solutions. If $k \neq 3,$ there are no solutions.

Yogi Berra once said "You can see a lot by looking." In this situation, the form of the augmented matrix says a lot. You don't really need Gauss-Jordan to answer your question (modulo a few mental calculations and miscellaneous facts).

Welcome to MSE. Enjoy your time here. There are many supremely qualified users you may find yourself interacting with.